# Solve a differential equation by Fourier transform $ y''+6y'+5y=\delta (t).e^{-t}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-transform

Solve a differential equation by Fourier transform:
$ y''+6y'+5y=\delta (t).e^{-t}$

I know Fourier transform of $\delta (t)$ and $H(t).e^{-t} $ but I can't determine Fourier transform of  $\delta (t).e^{-t}$.

Could you give me some hints? Thanks for helping

Comment: What definition of the fourier transform are you using?

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** $$\delta(x-x_{0})f(x)=\delta(x-x_{0})f(x_{0})$$

Comment: @qbert He says he knows the transform of the delta function. He can use this to simplify $$\delta(t)e^{-t}=\:?$$

Comment: @qbert this says that $\delta(t)e^{-t}=\delta(t)$, so $\mathcal F[\delta(t)e^{-t}]=\mathcal F[\delta(t)]$

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to memorize Fourier transforms, just how to integrate delta!
$$
\mathcal{F}(\delta(t)e^{-t})(\xi)=
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-2\pi i \xi t}e^{-t}\delta(t)\mathrm dt\\
=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-2\pi i \xi t}e^{-t}\vert_{t=0}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}
$$